Meaning of $d\mathcal{L}=-H$ in analytical mechanics?
In Lagrangian mechanics the momentum is defined as:
$$p=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot q}$$
Also we can define it as:
$$p=\frac{\partial S}{\partial  q}$$
where $S$ is Hamilton's principal function.
From that we have:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot q}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial q}$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}dt}{\partial  q}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial  q}$$
$$d\mathcal{L}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial  t}$$
But the Hamilton-Jacobi PDE is
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial  t}=-H$$
so we get:
$$d\mathcal{L}=-H$$
Thus we get that the change of the Lagrangian is equal to the negative Hamiltonian. Does that have any physical meaning? Or is it just gibberish and I am not allowed to make such algebraic manipulations?

I think it is gibberish in your own words. $\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}}$ cannot be replaced by $dt \frac{\partial}{\partial {q}}$ even in the most cavalier approach because $\dot{q} = \frac{dq}{dt}$, not $\frac{q}{dt}$.

Apart from the fact that I am really skeptical about its mathematical validity, your replacement $\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}}\rightarrow\frac{dt}{\partial q}$ makes little sense in the context of the Lagrangian formalism since position $q$ and velocity $\dot{q}$ are treated as entirely independent variables. What does have physical meaning is expressing the Hamiltonian as the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian.
